# What options are available for cross platform resource bundle editors?

Tags: editor, internationalization

We're releasing a new set of resource bundles for a large open source project, and I'd like to make some good recommendations for cross platform resource bundle editors to translators.

The only useful candidates I can find include:

- [RBManager](http://www.icu-project.org/download/rbmanager.html)
- [Eclipse ResourceBundle Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-rbe/)

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have just created OpenOffice XSL filters that read/write to/from my resource files, rather than rely on an external resource file editor because I found that most translators are familiar with spreadsheets but not with resource files. I wrote more about it in my post on: [managing the string translation process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191066/how-do-you-manage-the-string-translation-process#277508).